# minus disappears in the formula in latex

Tags: latex, tabular

In the last formula[image: here], I can not see the `-` sign. How to get around with this? many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,filecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newcommand{\etal}{{\sl et al. }}
\newcommand{\argmax}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmax}}
\newcommand{\iid}{\stackrel{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}

%\pdfminorversion=4
% NOTE: To produce blinded version, replace "0" with "1" below.
\newcommand{\blind}{0}

% DON'T change margins - should be 1 inch all around.
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}%
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.3in}%
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.8in}%




\begin{document}
    \begin{footnotesize}
        \begin{longtable} 
            { >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm} 
                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{12cm}}
            \caption{Variable definition }
            \label{tab:long}
            \\
            \toprule
            Variable  & Definition  \\
            \toprule
            \endfirsthead
            %\caption\[\]{Financial }\\
            % \multicolumn{5}{c}%
            % {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
            \toprule
            Variable  & Definition \\
            \toprule
            \endhead
            \bottomrule 
            %\multicolumn{5}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
            \endfoot
            \bottomrule 
            \endlastfoot
                    Constituency Statute &  The dummy is equal to one if the state s where firm $i$ incorporates has adopted constituency statute in year t; equal to zero if firm $i$’s incorporation state $s$ has not yet adopted its constituency statute in year $t$ but will adopt it sometime in later years, or firm $i$’s  incorporation state $s$ has never passed constituency statute.   \\
            Executive Horizon %& $Vested\,Equity_{t} = Unvested\,Equity_{t-1} + Equity\,Grant_{t}$    \\
                               &    $Vested\,Equity_{t} = Unvested\,Equity_{t-1} + Equity\,Grant_{t} − Unvested\,Equity_{t}$ \\
\end{longtable}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please copy&paste your code again? All the `[...]` are messed up because it was used inside an image

Comment: Please edit your question to fix the malformed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- An error message will tell you `Unicode character − (U+2212) not set up for use with LaTeX. ...sted\,Equity_{t-1} + Equity\,Grant_{t} −`. If you replace the unicode character with a normal `-`, your code compiles. (alternatively, you could use an unicode aware engine like lualatex or xelatex, but even there a normal `-` would be better ...)
- however you should never use math mode for multi-letter words, all the kerning is completely messed up. You can use `\text{...}` instead.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,filecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newcommand{\etal}{{\sl et al. }}
\newcommand{\argmax}{\operatornamewithlimits{argmax}}
\newcommand{\iid}{\stackrel{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}

%\pdfminorversion=4
% NOTE: To produce blinded version, replace "0" with "1" below.
\newcommand{\blind}{0}

% DON'T change margins - should be 1 inch all around.
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}%
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.3in}%
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.8in}%




\begin{document}
    \begin{footnotesize}
        \begin{longtable} 
            { >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm} 
                >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{12cm}}
            \caption{Variable definition }
            \label{tab:long}
            \\
            \toprule
            Variable  & Definition  \\
            \toprule
            \endfirsthead
            %\caption[]{Financial }\\
            % \multicolumn{5}{c}%
            % {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
            \toprule
            Variable  & Definition \\
            \toprule
            \endhead
            \bottomrule 
            %\multicolumn{5}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
            \endfoot
            \bottomrule 
            \endlastfoot
                    Constituency Statute &  The dummy is equal to one if the state s where firm $i$ incorporates has adopted constituency statute in year t; equal to zero if firm $i$’s incorporation state $s$ has not yet adopted its constituency statute in year $t$ but will adopt it sometime in later years, or firm $i$’s  incorporation state $s$ has never passed constituency statute.   \\
            Executive Horizon & $\text{Vested Equity}_{t} = \text{Unvested Equity}_{t-1} + \text{Equity Grant}_{t}$    \\
                               &    $\text{Vested Equity}_{t} = \text{Unvested Equity}_{t-1} + \text{Equity Grant}_{t} - \text{Unvested Equity}_{t}$ \\
\end{longtable}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{document}
```

[image]